# Text elements differ in size across websites

Tags: html, css

I have two paragraph elements, one on a blank site, and one on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/. When I hover over the one on the blank site using the inspect element tool, it says it is 43.98px by 13.64px in size. But when I hover over the one on MDN, it is 42.43px by 19.09px in size.

What CSS property could be affecting their size? They are both the same font and font size.

Here is the CSS I have set for both of them in a `style` attribute:

```css
#text {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  top: 7px;
  left: 8px;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: have you checked line-height?

Comment: @Codesigner Yep, it was line-height. If you want you can leave an answer for other people that might also have this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the CSS `line-height` property.

Answer (score 3):

Websites are made up of a set of instructions spoken in a web code language, most often HTML or CSS. Often, different browsers interpret code languages differently, which results in different interpretations.

For example, Safari defaults to the Helvetica family and Microsoft's Internet Explorer defaults to the Arial font family. Referenced (https://virteom.com/why-does-my-website-look-different-in-different-browsers)

You can use styling on the entire document body:

```
body{
    font-size: xxxx;
    font-family: xxxx;
    color: xxxx;
}
```

You can also try using "!important" after the attribute to make sure it applies.
I hope this answered your question.

Comment: They are different websites, but same browser. And same font.

Comment: Yes, but styling it into `body` and adding the attribute `!important` will "force" the styling. Also the other guy already answered but you should've checked `line-height`.